Poetry doesn't see torch when installing other libraries
I'm trying to install some package (in this particular example xformers, but this happens for other packages as well).
poetry run pip install xformers results in ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'. (The same will happen if I try poetry add).
However I can see torch installed inside poetry environment via:
poetry run python
>> import torch
>>

I can see that torch is imported in setup.py of xformers, but I don't understand why would that not use the one inside petry environment.
Torch is also installed in the environment that poetry is run in. So what kind of virtual environment is poetry using here that doesn't see torch?

There is an error with xformers https://github.com/facebookresearch/xformers/issues/740. I found this answer useful:

a trick way is to install torch correctly, you make sure yourself.
and then you just pip install xformers --no-dependencies

By the way I'd recommend to use poetry in a proper way poetry add xformers. Poetry creates and manages its own virtual environments.

I'm getting the same error when trying poetry add xformers

That's what the issue I mentioned is about)

I think with some help from the thread posted by Victor I found an answer.
Short answer: projects that fail are probably missing "build dependency" (e.g. [build-system] in pyproject.toml
Long answer: poetry indeed is creating separate python environment which is used to build packages. Each project should define what is required to build this package, via pyproject.toml (please note it's not the same as project dependencies like requirements.txt, it is definition of libraries that are necessary to build/install project). For example, you can define this in pyproject.toml:
[build-system]
requires = ["torch"]
build-backend

Now if some open-source project is missing that, but still wants some package (like torch) inside it's setup.py, this will fail to install via poetry. In overall, I don't know a good solution. Workaround could be to build the project yourself and add built .whl file to poetry.
= "pyproject.toml"
